# Is this .htacces config safe?

Tags: .htaccess

I was having trouble with some opensource software which I couldn't figure out. Eventually I found somebody with different problems but same error codes who solved it with adding the following lines to `.htaccess`:

```
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
allow from all
</Limit>
```

But I am not sure what this means and if it is safe in terms of security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional `<Limit>` container allows PUT and DELETE type requests, which have probably been disabled on the server. It is best practise to restrict access methods that are not required.

However, your software probably implements a REST API, in which case the PUT and DELETE request methods are probably required (hence your earlier error messages).

Incidentally, those two blocks can be combined:

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
allow from all
</Limit>
```

`.htaccess` files are per-directory Apache config files. If you have access to the main server config then they are not required and best disabled (performance and security). However if you are on a shared server you probably have no choice.